# USER~1 in user folder

Tags: windows-7, windows, filesystems, cmd.exe

After executing `cd %TEMP%` i was taken to `C:\Users\KRISWE~1\AppData\Local\Temp` I have never seen the folder `KRISWE~1` before, does anyone know what this is? It seems to be exactly identical to my regular user folder. It doesn't show up as a hidden folder, and i can only access it via `cd`. I noticed it's exactly 8 characters long, so i was thinking it might be some sort of hidden legacy system. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is another name for the same folder and is to provide compatibility with programs that don't support long file names.

Unless you have deliberately disabled the feature, every file and folder which has a name of more than 8 characters long, also has another name which is 8 characters long (and files that have extensions that are longer than 3 characters also have a short name that fits in the 8.3 space)

Microsoft documentation of this feature can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx#short_vs._long_names).
There is a sample algorithm showing how the short names are generated on page 30 of [this document](http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/6/1/161ba512-40e2-4cc9-843a-923143f3456c/fatgen103.doc).

If you open up a command prompt and run `Dir /X c:\users` , then it will show you both short and long names.

Answer (score 0):

This is your folder. Local user folder. To verify this, use the command:

```
set userp
```